# Render Unity stuff on top of native android studio project UI

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine

We have this requirement where we want to animate a character on top of our Native android studio app.

We want to do the character animation part in Unity, then merge the Android Studio export of that with our native app.

How can we show Unity stuff on top of native Android UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get started with `libunity` by reading this [blog post, "Add features powered by Unity to native mobile apps"](https://blogs.unity3d.com/en/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps/) and using a new enough version of Unity.